# How can I make SQLTABLE results link to outside pages?

Tags: web2py

New to Web2py, so my question might not be too clear.  I'm trying to make a shipment tracking page, and I have a simple database with a tracking number and a shipper ID.  Following the examples, my application can display and add new records to the shipment db.  Now I want to add links to the displayed records that will take you to the carrier's tracking page for that tracking number.  The tracking page URL will be created from a default string for each shipper to which the tracking number will be appended.  How can I make the results into links to the appropriate tracking page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are displaying the record via SQLFORM, Crud, SQLTABLE, or SQLFORM.grid, you could set the "represent" attribute of the tracking number field to display a link:

```
db.define_table('shipper',
    Field('name'),
    Field('url'),
    format='%(name)s')

db.define_table('shipment',
    Field('tracking_number', represent=lambda value, row: A(value,
        _href=row.shipper.url + value)),
    Field('shipper', db.shipper))
```

This assumes you are storing the shipper URLs in a separate table.

Comment: Getting this error when I try to add a shipment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'url'

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I was able to tweak it and make it work with some help from the folks at the [Web2py user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/web2py/Z1Zng7WmECE).  Check the answer below for the final version.

Answer (score 1):

I changed it to this, and it almost works:

```
db.define_table('carrier',
    Field('name',),
    Field('url',),
    format='%(name)s')

db.define_table('shipment',
    Field('shipment_id', represent=lambda value,row: \
        A(value, _href=(row.carrier.url + value, ))),
    Field('carrier', db.carrier))
```

shipment_id is a link, but it points to 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/tracker/default/www.bing.com/search?q=trumpet', where 'www.bing.com/search?q=' and 'trumpet' are the carrier.url and shipment.shipment_id values respectively (just for testing).  How can I leave off 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/tracker/default/'?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, ended up with:

```
db.define_table('carrier',
    Field('name',),
    Field('url',),
    format='%(name)s')

db.define_table('shipment',
    Field('shipment_id', represent=lambda value,row: \
        A(value, _href=row.carrier.url + value)),
    Field('carrier', db.carrier))
```

There were two problems.  First was the syntax of the href.  The version in the answer I added above didn't give an error, but caused the link address problem.  Second, the URLs were being entered without the "http://".  This caused the same link address issue.